# Task resume it is not functioning swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I am facing a sudden problem with task.resum for json file parsing below is my code:

```
let loadURL = "https:// ....."
var people = [Person]()

func getPersonData() {
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: loadURL)!)
let urlSession = URLSession.shared
let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { 
(data, response, error) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    // Parse JSON data
    if let data = data {
        self.people = self.parseJsonData(data)
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation{() -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
})
task.resume()
}

func parseJsonData(_ data: Data) -> [Person] {
var people = [Person]()

do {
    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, 
options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? 
NSDictionary

    // Parse JSON data
    let jsonPeople = jsonResult?["people"] as! [AnyObject]
    for jsonPerson in jsonPeople {
        let person = Person()
        person.name = jsonPerson["name"] as! String
        person.id = jsonPerson["id"] as! String

        //ERROR//: "unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping optional..."
        let jsonChildren = jsonResult?["children"] as! [AnyObject]
        for jsonChild in jsonChildren {
            let child = Child()
            child.name = jsonEntrance["name"] as! String
            child.age = jsonEntrance["age"] as! Int

            person.children.append(child)
        }

        people.append(person)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
return people
}
```

my problem is in this line:

```
task.resume()
```

after debugging, when the program reaches the above line it should go back to this code:

```
if let error = error {
    print(error)
    return
}
// Parse JSON data
if let data = data {
    self.people = self.parseJsonData(data)
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation{() -> Void in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

however, it just stops at it and does not work and just leaves the and the app continue working but the task does not resume.

The first time i tried it it was working, but then suddenly stopped any help please? thanx in advanced

Comment: Does the task not resume or does the parsing not work? The `URLSession` / `dataTask` code is correct. Add a line to print `jsonResult`, does it print anything? Not related to the issue, but why do you pass the `.mutableContainers` option however the result is assigned to an immutable object? And as always, never use `NSDictionary` and `AnyObject` in Swift 3 when parsing JSON.

Comment: @vadian Basically, I am using this code to parse a json file and grab urls, to be then downloaded and put in uiimage array to be displayed. But the task is not resuming at all it does not even start the json parsing. and why never use anyobject? thanks

Comment: Because the most unspecified JSON type in Swift 3 is `Any`. And be as type specific as possible: `jsonPeople` and `jsonChildren` are supposed to be `[[String:Any]]`, an array of dictionaries rather than an array of *something*. And replace `NSDictionary` with `[String:Any]` and use optional bindings (`if - let`).

Comment: I understand now but this did not affect the task resume first couple of times. Any idea why it is not working? @vadian

Comment: Once again the code related to URLSession looks correct (although the `URLRequest` is not needed for this case, just pass the URL to `dataTask(with:`). Is the URL correct? Does the URL return something when pasting it into a browser?

Comment: yes it does, it worked fine first couple times but now it is not. can it be a problem with xcode itself? can you write in the answer a cleaner version of my code this will help me a lot. thank you @vadian

Comment: Are  you sure that the `children` are a sub-node of `jsonResult`? If yes any person will get the same children. I suspect the `children` are a sub-node of `jsonPerson`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code, it eliminates some inconsistencies.

First the two model classes:

```
class Person {
    let name, id : String
    var children = [Child]()

    init(name: String, id: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    }
}

class Child {
    let name : String
    let age : Int

    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

Then the code to get and parse the JSON, I added debug messages

```
let loadURL = "https:// ....."
var people = [Person]()

func getPersonData() {
    let url = URL(string: loadURL)!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [unowned self] (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        // Parse JSON data
        if let data = data {
            self.people = self.parseJson(from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

func parseJson(from data: Data) -> [Person] {
    var people = [Person]()

    do {
        if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any] {

            // Parse JSON data
            if let jsonPeople = jsonResult["people"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                for jsonPerson in jsonPeople {
                    let person = Person(name: jsonPerson["name"] as! String, id: jsonPerson["id"] as! String)

                    if let jsonChildren = jsonPerson["children"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                        for jsonChild in jsonChildren {
                            let child = Child(name: jsonChild["name"] as! String, age: jsonChild["age"] as! Int)
                            person.children.append(child)
                        }
                        people.append(person)
                    }  else {
                        print("The value for key `children` is not an array or the key `children` does not exist")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("The value for key `people` is not an array or the key `people` does not exist")
            }
        } else {
            print("JSON root object is not a dictionary")
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return people
}
```